# Why \cref{} doesn't print names of multiple labels?

Tags: cleveref

I'm trying this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{rule}
\newcommand\printrule[1]{R#1}
\newcommand\orule[1]{\refstepcounter{rule}\label{#1}\printrule{\therule}: }
\crefname{rule}{Rule}{Rules}
\crefformat{rule}{#2\protect \printrule{#1}#3}
\orule{foo} Foo \\
\orule{bar} Bar \\
See \cref{foo}. \\
See \cref{foo,bar}.
\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

```
R1: Foo 
R2: Bar
See R1.
See ?? 1?? 2.
```

What is wrong? ChatGPT suggests that `\crefformat{rule}` should be replaced with `\crefformat{Rule}`, but it doesn't help :)

Comment: The problem vanishes if one moves the first fives lines after `\begin{document}` into the preamble. In particular, `See \cref{foo,bar}.` generates "See Rules 1 and 2."

Comment: @Mico you are right! If you post an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My main suggestion is that you move the first five lines of code after `\begin{document}` into the preamble.

In addition, if you want cross-references to rules be prefaced with the letter "R" automatically, I suggest you modify the macro `\therule` accordingly. With this change in place, all you need to do after loading the `cleveref` package is to provide suitable `\crefname` and `\Crefname` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{rule}
\renewcommand\therule{R\arabic{rule}}
\newcommand\orule[1]{\refstepcounter{rule}\label{#1}\therule:}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{rule}{rule}{rules}
\Crefname{rule}{Rule}{Rules}

\begin{document}
\orule{foo} Foo.

\orule{bar} Bar.

See \labelcref{foo}. \Cref{bar} expresses\dots\ See \cref{foo,bar}.
\end{document}
```